# Linear functions of independent normal variables and chance experiments

Tags: probability

Consider the following problem, from Tijms's *Understanding Probability*:

> The random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $N (\mu_1 , \sigma_1^2)$ and $N (\mu_2 , \sigma_2^2)$ distributed. Let the random variable $V$ be distributed as $X_1$ with given probability $p$ and as $X_2$ with probability $1 - p$. What is the probability density of $V$? Is this probability density the same as the probability density of the random variable $W = pX_1 + (1 - p)X_2$ when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Let us compute the probability density of $V$. The probability distribution is:
$$
\begin{align}
P(V\le v) &= P(V\le v| \text{we picked }X_1) + P(V\le v| \text{we picked }X_2) \\
&= p\int_{-\infty}^v \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}e^{-\frac12\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}}dx + (1-p)\int_{-\infty}^v \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}e^{-\frac12\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}}dx,
\end{align}
$$
thus the density function of $V$ is:
$$
f_V(v) = \frac{d P(V\le v)}{dv} =
\frac{p}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}e^{-\frac12\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}} +
\frac{1-p}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}e^{-\frac12\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}}.
$$

For $W$, we have:
$$
P(W\le v) = \int_{-\infty}^v \left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}e^{-\frac12\frac{(x\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}} + \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}e^{-\frac12\frac{(x\mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}}\right)dx,
$$
which is the same integral that we had to compute for determining the probability distribution of $V$.
So the two probability densities of $V$ and $W$ are the same.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  $W$ is a linear combination (or if you prefer: weighted average) of two Gaussians, and is itself a Gaussian, in fact with mean $E[W] = p \mu_1 + (1-p) \mu_2$.  So your CDF $P(W \le v)$ is all wrong.

If you want, you can look up [sum of Gaussians on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) or similar sources.

However, a quick thought experiment should convince you $V$ and $W$ are entirely different.  Imagine $X_1 = N(0,1)$ and $X_2 = N(1000000, 1)$.  Then $V$ will be very likely to be near either $0$ or $1000000$ (it is bimodal).  Meanwhile say for $p=0.5, W$ will be very likely to be near $500000$ (it is still Gaussian, and unimodal).